# Does MongoDB Stitch Functions support async/await definitions?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await, mongodb-stitch

Asynchronous function definitions on MongoDB (Atlas) Stitch display warnings on the GUI editor. Including the example code provided on the reference for Triggers.

The code found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/) can be was copied over directly to the Stitch Function editor and produces warnings because of the async keyword.

Example code from the docs.

```
exports = async function (changeEvent) {
  // Destructure out fields from the change stream event object
  const { updateDescription, fullDocument } = changeEvent;

  // Check if the shippingLocation field was updated
  const updatedFields = Object.keys(updateDescription.updatedFields);
  const isNewLocation = updatedFields.some(field =>
    field.match(/shippingLocation/)
  );

  // If the location changed, text the customer the updated location.
  if (isNewLocation) {
    const { customerId, shippingLocation } = fullDocument;
    const twilio = context.services.get("myTwilioService");
    const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
    const customers = mongodb.db("store").collection("customers");

    const { location } = shippingLocation.pop();
    const customer = await customers.findOne({ _id: customer_id })
    twilio.send({
      to: customer.phoneNumber,
      from: context.values.get("ourPhoneNumber"),
      body: `Your order has moved! The new location is ${location}.`
    });
  }
};
```

I want to know if Stitch supports the async/await paradigm and if I should be concerned about the warnings shown.

Comment: What does the warning actually say? After all its just a warning ...

Comment: Most just say missing semicolon. After some trial and error I found that a semicolon after the `async` keyword made it stop showing but of course that seems to be it's linter messing up.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I found that at this time the `async/await` keywords cause the linter to throw errors and warnings. This means that for async callbacks it is best to define them separately as it will improve the linting. IE. `[].map(async () => {})` will prompt errors that can be worked around.

The runtime execution returns the results as expected from standard asynchronous operations.

Comment: Hi, have same problem and would like to get rid of these warnings. Could you elaborate a little bit more how to fix please ? Thanks.

Comment: In short, the execution works as expected. The linter has a false issue.

Comment: OK, true that it works despite these warnings. Nevertheless, I experienced a big difference in response times when using async/await instead of classic promises syntax (3-4 times slower). Did you ?

Comment: I did not encounter this, probably because we never tried pure Promises. If to speculate I suppose the Javascript runtime does better internal optimizations when using async/await syntax sugar.

Comment: In fact that's the contrary, async/await much slower than promises